# Generate or mine pgp key with specific key id

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Is it possible to generate or somehow mine a PGP key that its key id would be a specific key id? Say for instance get a PGP key with key id -> 0x5F38FF00

Comment: For the short (32-bit) keyid, this is (now) practical; see https://evil32.com/ . For the long (64-bit) keyid, it probably takes years at least. This isn't really a programming Q and fits better on security.SX where it is very close to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74009/what-is-an-openpgp-key-id-collision

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 it's exactly what I mean. I've asked moderators to migrate this Q to security.stackexchange.com. thanks